# How to properly stretch your Iliotibial Band?

Tags: stretching

I've recently heard [about having a tight Iliotibial Band](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t32xJspx50o) and how its important to stretch it.

However since I've been stretching it (gentle 30 second stretches, a variety of them in succession), *it seems to be getting tighter*.

I don't know why this is or what I'm doing wrong, **so I would like to know how to properly stretch my Iliotibial Band?**

Comment: The edit missed the point of the question.  Even when I do stretch, it feels fine at first, but then it feels _even tighter_ than it originally was after about 20 minutes.

Comment: The most likely reason is that you were stretching it the wrong way. The edit still includes `it seems to be getting tighter.` Which should be clear enough. If you want the answerers to address it specifically, simply add a line asking for it or leave a comment on their answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one's going to know this, but no amount of stretching helped.  The area was inflamed.

Rest, Tylenol, and sticking with bikes/rowers, **and avoiding overstretching the hip muscle** seem to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Exercise Prescription (ExRx.net) site, there are [a few exercises and stretches](http://exrx.net/Kinesiology/Inflexibilities.html) you can do.

**Testing:**

- [Ober's Test](http://exrx.net/Testing/FlexFunction/ObersTest.html)

**Affected Exercises:**

- [Barbell Lunges](http://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/BBLunge.html)
- [Barbell Stepup](http://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/BBStepUp.html)

**Corrective Exercises and Stretches:**

- [Standing Iliotibial Stretch](http://exrx.net/Stretches/HipAbductors/StandingIliotibial.html)
- [Lying Glute Stretch](http://exrx.net/Stretches/GluteusMaximus/Lying.html)
- [Lever Seated Hip Abduction](http://exrx.net/WeightExercises/HipAbductor/LVSeatedHipAbduction.html)

Comment: Well, I'm trying these.  But my problem still remains -- even if I stretch a lot, after about 20 minutes, it seems it snaps back into being _even tighter_ than it was before.

Comment: The first question is: are you stretching cold?  You do need to properly warm up before and cool down afterwards.  Stretching cold muscles is counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the foam roller technique you may be overdoing it and causing irritation, which is why you feel you are counterproductive.  You may want to try just lying on your side, placing a tennis ball or softer "miracle ball"  under the tight spot and gently letting the weight of your leg and gravity release the tightness.

- This video shows the [ball release technique for the ITB and quads](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAuv9BUq_yY).
- This video shows standing [stretches for the ITB/TFL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI1uUQv7u1k&feature=related).
- And [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlYM3KWwrGY&feature=related) shows a stretch that also includes the hip rotators.

Hope that helps